# RecyclerView doesn't load XML

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter, picasso

My app loads some items into the recycler view and sets an onClickListeners for each of them. Two hours ago I had the problem where Picasso, Glide or asyncronous task, all of them loaded fine the first 2 or 4 images, then it started loading it randomly (only the images, the textview and the item itself was fine) and flickering sometimes beetween different images.

I've started changing my code to try and fix it and now, the recycler view doesn't load anything.

Can someone take o look at my code? I only touched these 2 classes.

Edit: This is how it look now https://i.stack.imgur.com/28xHA.jpg

Edit2: using debug, the program never enters the onBindViewHolder or onCreateViewHolder methods

Main Activity

```
public class Principal extends AppCompatActivity implements AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener{
    public static LugaresBD lugares;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    public static AdaptadorLugares adaptador;
    private android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    static final int RESULTADO_PREFERENCIAS = 0;
    static public ArrayList<Lugar> arrayLugares = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        lugares = new LugaresBD(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)
                findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        adaptador = new AdaptadorLugares(this, lugares, lugares.extraeCursor());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adaptador);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


        adaptador.setOnItemClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Principal.this,
                        VistaLugarActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("id", arrayLugares.get(recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(v)).get_id());
                startActivityForResult(i, 1433);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Adapter

```
public class AdaptadorLugares extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdaptadorLugares.ViewHolder> {
        protected Cursor cursor;
        protected Lugares lugares; //Lugares a mostrar
        protected LayoutInflater inflador; //Crea Layouts con el XML
        protected Context contexto; //Lo necesitamos para el inflador
        protected View.OnClickListener onClickListener;
        public static ImageView foto;
        AsyncTask<String,Void,Bitmap> task = null;
        Bitmap mBitmap;

    public AdaptadorLugares(Context contexto, Lugares lugares, Cursor cursor){
        this.cursor = cursor;
        this.contexto = contexto;
        this.lugares = lugares;
        inflador = (LayoutInflater) contexto.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }



        public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public TextView nombre;

            public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                nombre = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nombrecito);
                foto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.foto);

            }
        }


        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            // Inflamos la vista desde el xml
            View v = inflador.inflate(R.layout.elemento_lista, parent,
                    false);
            v.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
            return new ViewHolder(v);
        }


        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int posicion) {
            Lugar lugar = lugares.elemento(posicion);

            holder.nombre.setText(lugar.get_id() + lugar.getNombre());
            Picasso.with(contexto).load(lugar.getImage()).into(foto);



        }



        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return lugares.tamanyo();
        }

        public void setOnItemClickListener(View.OnClickListener onClickListener) {
            this.onClickListener = onClickListener;
        }

        public Cursor getCursor(){
            return cursor;
        }

        public void setCursor(Cursor cursor){
            this.cursor = cursor;
        }

        public Lugar lugarPosicion(int posicion){
            cursor.moveToPosition(posicion);
            return LugaresBD.extraeLugar(cursor);
        }

        public int idPosicion(int posicion){
            cursor.moveToPosition((posicion));
            return cursor.getInt(0);
        }
}
```

Thank you.

Edit3:

Activity Main xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/main.imageview.placeholder"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/street_view"
                android:tint="#11000000"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.9"
                />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/main.framelayout.title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:background="@color/primary"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.3"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/main.linearlayout.title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:gravity="bottom|center"
                        android:text="ITEMS"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="30sp"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:text="My store STORE"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        />

                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:behavior_overlapTop="30dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/main.backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            />
        <include layout="@layout/content_principal" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/main.toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/main.framelayout.title"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        app:title=""
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <Space
                android:layout_width="@dimen/image_final_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/image_final_width"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/main.textview.title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="My Store"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/circleView"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/image_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/image_width"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        app:border_color="@android:color/white"
        app:border_width="2dp"
        app:finalHeight="@dimen/image_final_width"
        app:finalYPosition="2dp"
        app:layout_behavior="com.example.dam202.mislugares.AvatarImageBehavior"
        app:startHeight="2dp"
        app:startToolbarPosition="2dp"
        app:startXPosition="2dp"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_principal.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".Principal"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: in the ViewHolder why don't you use `public ImageView foto;`?

Comment: It's declared as public static ImageView foto;

Comment: I've just did it now but I still have the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to flip the order code when you set the adapter and set the linear layout of recyclerview. Because RecyclerView won't work if it doesn't have layout manager. So we have to set the linear layout first and adapter after it. It will be like this :

```
layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
adaptador = new AdaptadorLugares(this, lugares, lugares.extraeCursor());
recyclerView.setAdapter(adaptador);
```

Then try to put `public ImageView foto;` to your ViewHolder class. So it will be like this:

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView foto;
    public TextView nombre;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        nombre = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nombrecito);
        foto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.foto);
     }
}
```

And also use the `holder` inside `onBindViewHolder()`. So it will be like this :

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int posicion) {
        Lugar lugar = lugares.elemento(posicion);

        holder.nombre.setText(lugar.get_id() + lugar.getNombre());
        Picasso.with(contexto).load(lugar.getImage()).into(holder.foto);
    }
```

And make sure `getItemCount()` is return more than zero

Comment: I just edit it. You have to use the holder man, this is the right way to use recycler view :D

Comment: And you don't need to declare it outside of ViewHolder class :D
That is the purpose of ViewHolder of RecyclerView :D

Comment: Just removed the   static ImageView    from above and put it exactly like your code. The reciclerView still doesn't load anything

Comment: Using debug it never enters the onCreateViewHolder or onBindViewHolder methods

Comment: are u sure `lugares.tamanyo();` is returning > 0? if yes then try to flip the order code of adapter and layout manager. It will be like this         
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
adaptador = new AdaptadorLugares(this, lugares, lugares.extraeCursor());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adaptador);

Comment: Because the adapter will not work if recycler view doesn't has linear layout. So we have to set the linear layout first, and set adapter after

Comment: Change it and still doesn't work. I think that maybe the problem is in the XML file. I'll edit my answer with the code

Comment: I don't think so. because you said that onCreateViewHolder and onBindViewHolder never got called. As i know it never get called because RecyclerView has no layout manager or getItemCount() return 0

Comment: I change it. Put first setAdapter then setLayout and it still returns 0. And the other way too. It return 0

Comment: More debugging: It never enters the cursor to extract the items from SQLite.

Comment: I know now why I return always 0. I have return 0 in that method. But now I dont know what I have to return instead. Silly me

Comment: Me again. It's solved now. Thank you both very much. The problem was that method on getItemCount(). And maybe something more but who knows. And it even solved my first problem too :P

Comment: Haaa glad to hear that :D.. Btw sorry for late response